# SSH from pexpect (pxssh) fails when I try from a linux machine to a windows ssh client server

Tags: python, linux, windows, ssh, pxssh

I'm trying to run a python script which ssh from a linux machine to a windows server and runs a batch file.

After some research, I realized that a pxssh class from pexpect is a ood module to use. When I try this module on linux to ssh to linux machine there is no problem. When I do it from a linux to windows it fails with the following error :
pxssh failed on login.

```
pxssh failed on login.
could not set shell prompt (received: ": \r\n\x1b[2J\x1b[1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]\r\n(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\myname>unset PROMPT_COMMAND\nPS1='[PEXPECT]\\$ '\nset prompt='[PEXPECT]\\$ '\n", expected: '\\[PEXPECT\\][\\$\\#] ').
```

I remember from before windows had different way of ending lines and such (carriage return etc) from linux. I would like to know if anyway knows a solution to this problem.
Please note that I'm manually able to use a shell from linux machine and ssh to a windows machine, it only fails when I try to write a python script and use pxssh.
Thank you for your help.
Please note that my next step would be to run a batch file and close the connection.
My simple script:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:                                                            
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    #hostname = raw_input('hostname: ')
    #username = raw_input('username: ')
    #password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login ('192.168.0.144', 'username', 'password',  auto_prompt_reset=True)
    s.sendline ('dir')
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    s.sendline ('exit')
    s.logout()
    print "I'm here"
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
    print "pxssh failed on login."
    print str(e)
```

I use exit instead of logout because I think ssh client server on windows doesn't support logout

Edit: I have disabled the auto_prompt_reset now I got the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sshLogin.py", line 22, in <module>
    s.logout()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 355, in logout
    index = self.expect([EOF, "(?i)there are stopped jobs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 321, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 345, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 107, in expect_loop
    return self.timeout(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 70, in timeout
    raise TIMEOUT(msg)
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded.
<pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0xb72491cc>
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', 'username@192.168.0.144']
buffer (last 100 chars): 'Version 10.0.14393]\r\n(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\myname>exit\n'
before (last 100 chars): 'Version 10.0.14393]\r\n(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\myname>exit\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: False
pid: 4523
child_fd: 5
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: EOF
    1: re.compile("(?i)there are stopped jobs")
```

Some resource which might be useful:
http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html

Comment: *"... from before windows had different way of ending lines and such (carriage return etc) from linux. I would like to know if anyway knows a solution to this problem."* - The SSH protocol (there are multiple RFCs) uses `CRLF` as the line ending (`CRLF` is WIndows; Linux is `LF`; OS X is `CR`). Use of `CRLF` is consistent with other RFCs, like Telnet, Privacy Enhanced Mail, and FTP. These are some of the oldest RFCs, and they have been around 30 or 40 years. It sounds like the Python software is broken if it can't handle `CRLF`. But I am not convinced line endings are the problem.

Comment: *`pxssh failed on login`* - I'm guessing (and its just a guess), that the password on Windows is not what you expect. Can you forgo password authentication, and use public key authentication? If not, can you verify or confirm the password is what you expect? For question (2), verify or confirm the password, its probably not the Windows password you use to log into your machine unless you specifically set it to such.

Comment: @jww I really don't think there is any problem with log-in. As you see from the buffer, the shs is able to retrieve some information :Version 10.0.14393]\r\n(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nC:\\Users\\myname>exit\n

Comment: I can't figure out how this works: original_prompt=r"[#$]" this is an iput parameter to login method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the login parameters as follow solved my problem

```
s.login(server= hostname, username=username, password='', terminal_type='ansi',
            original_prompt=r"[#$]", login_timeout=10, port=22,
            auto_prompt_reset=False, ssh_key=None, quiet=True,
            sync_multiplier=1, check_local_ip=True)
```

However, the connection is still very slow and I cannot launch a program remotely.
Also another hint: In order to use the sendline method add carriage to the beginning and end of your string